# Hibernate Join issue while joining more than 2 tables

Tags: hibernate

I am working on a application where I have to join 3-4 tables for a select operation.
I am **hibernate 3 with annotations** and added my class structure below.however I have tried using many variations in the Join fetch strategy,but not able to get the result in **2 selects**. Please go through and try to help me out.
**Candidates class**

```
@JsonAutoDetect
@Entity
@Table(name="HC_RESUME_BANK")
public class Candidates{

private int id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private String phone;
@JsonUnwrapped  
private Set<CandidateStatus> candidateStats = new HashSet<CandidateStatus>(0);

@OneToMany  //(mappedBy="candidate")
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name="ResID",nullable=false,referencedColumnName="RID")
@JsonIgnore
public Set<CandidateStatus> getCandidateStats() {
        return candidateStats;
}
public void setCandidateStats(Set<CandidateStatus> candidateStats) {
    this.candidateStats = candidateStats;
}
```

**CandidateStatus class**

```
@JsonAutoDetect
@Entity

@Table(name="HC_REQ_RESUME")

public class CandidateStatus{

private int id;
private String statusTitle;
@JsonUnwrapped
private Candidates candidate;
private int reqid;
private int resid;

@JsonUnwrapped
private Requirements requirement;

@ManyToOne
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)

@JoinColumn(name="ReqID",insertable=false,updatable=false)
//@JsonIgnore
public Requirements getRequirement() {
    return requirement;
}
    @ManyToOne //(fetch =    FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,targetEntity=Candidates.class)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name="ResID",insertable=false,updatable=false)
//@ForeignKey(name = "FK_ResID")

public Candidates getCandidate() {
    return candidate;
}

public void setCandidate(Candidates candidate) {
    this.candidate = candidate;
}
```

**Clients class**

```
 @JsonAutoDetect
 @Entity
 @Table(name="HC_CLIENTS")
 public class Clients{

private int id;
private String clientName;
@JsonUnwrapped
private Set<Requirements> require= new HashSet<Requirements>(0);
//private List<Requirements> require;


@OneToMany  //(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name="ClientID",referencedColumnName="RID")


@JsonIgnore
public Set<Requirements> getRequire() {
    return require;
}
public void setRequire(Set<Requirements> require) {
    this.require = require;
}
```

and finally **Requirements class**

```
@JsonAutoDetect
@Entity

@Table(name="HC_REQUISITIONS")
public class Requirements{

private int id;
private int clientId;
private String reqTitle;
@JsonUnwrapped
private Clients client;

@ManyToOne
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name="ClientID",insertable=false,updatable=false)
//@JsonIgnore
public Clients getClient() {
    return client;
}
public void setClient(Clients client) {
    this.client = client;
}
    @OneToMany
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name="ReqID",referencedColumnName="RID")
@JsonIgnore
public Set<CandidateStatus> getCandidateStatus() {
    return candidateStatus;
}
public void setCandidateStatus(Set<CandidateStatus> candidateStatus) {
    this.candidateStatus = candidateStatus;
}
```

I have eliminated the **Getter/Setter** methods for avoiding unnessary code.
What is wrong in the above association of classes due to which N+1 occurs?
**Query is:**

```
    return hibernateTemplate.find("from Requirements as req order by req.reqTitle");
```

I want to fetch only **Requirement class' objects** but I get all the objects and a N+1 result of queries

Thank you for your time
Sachin

@RaulGogo: Tried the criteria query but the problem persists.These are the log instances of the query.And I added **@BatchSize(size=100)** which reduces the no of queries by doing batch fetch.Any thing that I have missed in terms of annotation config?

```
    Hibernate: 
    /* criteria query */ select
    this_.RID as RID3_3_,
    this_.ClientID as ClientID3_3_,
    this_.ReqTitle as ReqTitle3_3_,
    candidates2_.ReqID as ReqID3_5_,
    candidates2_.RID as RID5_,
    candidates2_.RID as RID1_0_,
    candidates2_.ResID as ResID1_0_,
    candidates2_.reqid as reqid1_0_,
    candidates2_.ReqID as ReqID1_0_,
    candidates2_.resid as resid1_0_,
    candidates2_.StatusTitle as StatusTi4_1_0_,
    candidates3_.RID as RID0_1_,
    candidates3_.EmailID as EmailID0_1_,
    candidates3_.FirstName as FirstName0_1_,
    candidates3_.LastName as LastName0_1_,
    candidates3_.Mobile as Mobile0_1_,
    clients4_.RID as RID2_2_,
    clients4_.ClientName as ClientName2_2_ 
from
    HC_REQUISITIONS this_ 
left outer join
    HC_REQ_RESUME candidates2_ 
        on this_.RID=candidates2_.ReqID 
left outer join
    HC_RESUME_BANK candidates3_ 
        on candidates2_.ResID=candidates3_.RID 
left outer join
    HC_CLIENTS clients4_ 
        on this_.ClientID=clients4_.RID 
order by
    this_.ReqTitle asc

  Hibernate: 
  /* load one-to-many com.options.model.Candidates.candidateStats */ select
    candidates0_.ResID as ResID0_3_,
    candidates0_.RID as RID3_,
    candidates0_.RID as RID1_2_,
    candidates0_.ResID as ResID1_2_,
    candidates0_.reqid as reqid1_2_,
    candidates0_.ReqID as ReqID1_2_,
    candidates0_.resid as resid1_2_,
    candidates0_.StatusTitle as StatusTi4_1_2_,
    requiremen1_.RID as RID3_0_,
    requiremen1_.ClientID as ClientID3_0_,
    requiremen1_.ReqTitle as ReqTitle3_0_,
    clients2_.RID as RID2_1_,
    clients2_.ClientName as ClientName2_1_ 
from
    HC_REQ_RESUME candidates0_ 
left outer join
    HC_REQUISITIONS requiremen1_ 
        on candidates0_.ReqID=requiremen1_.RID 
left outer join
    HC_CLIENTS clients2_ 
        on requiremen1_.ClientID=clients2_.RID 
where
    candidates0_.ResID=?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using criteria.

```
return getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback<List<Requirement>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Requirement>doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
            return (List<Requirement>) session.createCriteria(Requirement.class)
                    .addOrder(Order.asc("reqTitle"))
                    .list();
        }
    });
```

This does a **select * from Requirement order by reqTitle asc** and it will return a list of Requirements.

Comment: Thanks @RaulGogo `select
        this_.ClientID as ClientID3_3_,
        this_.ReqTitle as ReqTitle3_3_,
        from
        HC_REQUISITIONS this_
    left outer join
    HC_REQ_RESUME candidates2_
       on this_.RID=candidates2_.ReqID
    left outer join
        HC_RESUME_BANK candidates3_
        on candidates2_.ResID=candidates3_.RID 
    left outer join
    HC_CLIENTS clients4_
            on this_.ClientID=clients4_.RID 
    order by
        this_.ReqTitle asc
`This is a part of the log query printed.It still prints **N+1 queries** with joins.Character limit so cant post entire logs.

Comment: Updated the question for your answer.Please go through.                Thanks

Comment: Added **.setFetchMode(FetchMode.LAZY)**,but did not change the result.Also,BatchFetch helps but is it the **best solution among the Fetch Strategies**?